# Определение ip адреса

Tags: геолокация, ip

Как узнать ip адрес и определить по ip из какого города входят на сайт?

Comment: proverim.net

Comment: [Проверка IP по стране и вывод](http://hashcode.ru/questions/15771/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-ip-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4). Аналогично для города.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, получить IP не проблема:

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

А дальше, почитайте о [Geo IP Location](http://www.php.ru/manual/book.geoip.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
function geo_info($ip)
{
$xml = '<ipquery><fields><city/></fields><ip-list>'
. '<ip>'.$ip.'</ip></ip-list></ipquery>';
$ch = curl_init('http://194.85.91.253:8090/geo/geo.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch) != 0)
die('curl_errno('.curl_errno($ch).'), curl_error('.curl_error($ch).')');
curl_close($ch);
if (strpos($result, '<message>Not found</message>') !== false)
return false;
preg_match('/<city>(.*)<\/city>/', $result, $city);
return $city[1];
}

//Пример использования:
/* IP адрес клиента */
$city = geo_info($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); // Вернет город посетителя
Echo'Ваш город: '.$city;
```

[оригинал](http://www.websr.ru/opredelenie-goroda-po-ip.html)

Comment: спасибо, хотя мой город я так и не узнал 8-( ip 46.146.49.*** , страница выдала

    curl_errno(7), curl_error(couldn't connect to host)
